# Proof by induction of Gronwall's inequality

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, alternative-proof, proof-explanation

I've an exercise which is the following:

> **Gronwall’s Inequality**
>
> Let $A > 0, B \geq  0$. 
>   Let $(\epsilon_j)_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of real numbers with 
>   $$|\epsilon_{j+1}| \leq (1 + A) | \epsilon_j| + B$$
>   for $j=0,1 ...$.
>
> Prove by induction that, for $A > B$ it holds that
>   $$|\epsilon_j| \leq |\epsilon_0| \exp(jA) + \frac{B}{A}(\exp(jA) - 1)$$
>   for $j = 0,1..$

So, here's my proof attempt, which I think is correct, but I'm not $100\%$ sure.

---

**Base case**

$j = 0$

$$|\epsilon_0| \leq |\epsilon_0| e^{0A} + \frac{B}{A}(e^{0A} - 1) = |\epsilon_0|$$

**Induction hypothesis**

Lets assume that 
$$|\epsilon_j| \leq |\epsilon_j| e^{jA} + \frac{B}{A}(e^{jA} - 1)$$ is true for an arbitrary $j$.

**Induction step**

$$|\epsilon_{j+1}| \leq (1 + A) |\epsilon_j| + B$$

Now, I'm going to use the induction hypothesis

$$|\epsilon_{j+1}| \leq (1 + A) (|\epsilon_j| * e^{jA} + \frac{B}{A}(e^{jA} - 1)) + B$$

Now I use the fact that $(1 + A) \leq e^{A}$.

$$|\epsilon_{j+1}| \leq e^{A}|\epsilon_j| e^{jA} + \frac{B}{A}(e^{jA} - 1)e^{A} + B$$

$$|\epsilon_{j+1}| \leq e^{A(j + 1)}|\epsilon_j| + \frac{B}{A}(e^{jA}e^{A} - e^{A}) + B$$

$$|\epsilon_{j+1}| \leq e^{A(j + 1)}|\epsilon_j| + \frac{B}{A}(e^{A(j + 1)} - e^{A}) + B$$

$$|\epsilon_{j+1}| \leq e^{A(j + 1)}|\epsilon_j| + \frac{B}{A}((e^{A(j + 1)} - e^{A}) + A)$$

Now I use again this fact $(1 + A) \leq e^{A}$, which is equivalent to $A - e^{A}\leq -1$

so we have

$$|\epsilon_{j+1}| \leq e^{A(j + 1)}|\epsilon_j| + \frac{B}{A}(e^{A(j + 1)} - e^{A} + A)$$

$$|\epsilon_{j+1}| \leq e^{A(j + 1)}|\epsilon_j| + \frac{B}{A}(e^{A(j + 1)} - 1)$$

---

What I'm not sure about is the last step (**but this doesn't mean there aren't other errors before**). My idea is that if we sum a greater number to any other number the result will be a greater number than summing a smaller number to the corresponding any number.

Comment: So you are wondering if we know A < B and we know y < x + A if we are allowed to conclude y < x + B?  The answer is yes.  A < B so x + A < x + B.  So we have y < x + A and we have x + A < x + B so by transitivity y < x + A < x + B.

Comment: BTW this $|\epsilon_0| \leq |\epsilon_0| e^{0A} + \frac{B}{A}(e^{0A} - 1) = |\epsilon_0|$ appears to be a typo.  I don't think you want the $ = |\epsilon_0|$.  I think you want just the $|\epsilon_0| \leq |\epsilon_0| e^{0A} + \frac{B}{A}(e^{0A} - 1)$.

Comment: Ah.  Well, so it does...